# error: definition of implicitly declared copy constructor

Tags: c++, qt, copy-constructor

I'm having issues with a Qt C++ Project that I'm working on at the moment. It's a new section that I'm covering and I'm finding it a bit confusing. I have created some classes Asset which is inherited by Stock, Bond and Savings classes. All this was okay. I then created a class called AssetList which derived QList, this class is where I have found the problem.

Here is the code I have so far.

AssetList.h

```
#ifndef ASSET_LIST_H
#define ASSET_LIST_H

#include "Asset.h"
#include <QString>

class AssetList : public QList<Asset*>
{
public:
    AssetList(){}
    ~AssetList();
    bool addAsset(Asset*);
    Asset* findAsset(QString);
    double totalValue(QString);
};

#endif
```

AssetList.cpp

```
#include "AssetList.h"

AssetList::AssetList(const AssetList&) : QList<Asset*>(){}
AssetList::~AssetList()
{
    qDeleteAll(*this);
    clear();
}

bool AssetList::addAsset(Asset* a)
{
    QString desc = a->getDescription();
    Asset* duplicate = findAsset(desc);

    if(duplicate == 0)
    {
        append(a);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        delete duplicate;
        return false;
    }
}

Asset* AssetList::findAsset(QString desc)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size() ; i++)
    {
        if(at(i)->getDescription() == desc)
        {
            return at(i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

double AssetList::totalValue(QString type)
{
    double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size() ; i++)
    {
        if(at(i)->getType() == type)
        {
            sum += at(i)->value();
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The error I'm getting at the moment is a compilation error: `error: definition of implicitly declared copy constructor` I'm not quite sure what this means, I've been googling around and looking in the textbook and haven't found much. Can anyone help me or put me in the right direction of figuring this out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *define* a copy constructor:

```
AssetList::AssetList(const AssetList&) : QList<Asset*>(){}
```

But you do not *declare* it in the `AssetList` class.

You need to add it:

```
class AssetList : public QList<Asset*>
{
public:
    AssetList(){}
    ~AssetList();
    AssetList(const AssetList&);  // Declaring the copy-constructor

    ...
};
```

Comment: If I just remove the declaration from the AssetList.h file, I get exactly the same error :/ Or am I misunderstanding what you're saying.

Comment: @nickcorin: You need to *add* a declaration to the class definition: `AssetList(const AssetList&);`

Comment: @nickcorin In the header file you show to use there is no declaration of the copy-constructor. You need to add it to the class.

Comment: Right sorry I misunderstood you! Thank you so much this worked perfectly! :) Could you explain why I need the blank constructor and the copy constructor and quite honestly what a "copy constructor" is for.

Comment: @nickcorin It's for when you do e.g. `AssetList l1; AssetList l2 = l1;` In the second declaration the copy-constructor is called on the `l2` object, with `l1` passed as argument. You might also want to read about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).